# Comparing definitions of smooth and unramified

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a base ring, and let $\mathsf{Aff}_k$ be the category of affine schemes over $k$. If $X$ is any presheaf on $\mathsf{Aff}_k$, one defines the associated "de Rham space" to be the presheaf 
$$
  X_\text{dR}:A \mapsto X(A/\text{nil}(A))  
$$
where $\text{nil}(A)$ is the nilradical of $A$. Traditionally, one says that $X$ is formally smooth (resp. unramified) if whenever $I\subset A$ is a nilpotent ideal, the map 
$X(A) \to X(A/I)$ is surjective (resp. injective). One could ask if the corresponding morphism $X\to X_\text{dR}$ is epic (resp. monic) as a morphism of presheaves. It is easy to check that if $X\to X_\text{dR}$ is monic, then $X$ is unramified, but the converse is not immediately obvious.

> Is $X$ formally smooth (resp. unramified) if and only if $X\to X_\text{dR}$ is epic (resp. monic)?

I'll be happy if there is an answer under assumptions like "$X$ is a variety" or "$X$ is a scheme."

**Edit:** one usually defines the notion of "formally etale scheme $X$ over $k$" by requiring that $X(A) \to X(A/I)$ be a bijection for *any* nilpotent ideal $I$. I am wondering if one can replace "any nilpotent ideal" with "the nilradical."

Comment: Interesting question. But I suspect that the answer is No in each case, for "silly" reasons. For example the nilradical doesn't have to be nilpotent (or do you restrict to noetherian affine schemes?). Have you checked the case of (affine) varieties?

Answer (score 0):

I will take $\mathbb{Z}$ as a base ring but of course the theory makes sense in general. Given a presheaf $X$ on $\mathsf{Aff}$, let's define its de Rham space in a slightly more refined way:
$$X_\text{dR}(R) := \operatorname{colim}_{I\subset R}X(R/I),$$
where the colimit runs through the nilpotent ideals $I$ of $R$. Using the Tag 01ZC on the Stacks Project, one can prove that $X_\text{dR}(R)\simeq X(R_\text{red})$ holds for every ring $R$ as long as $X$ is locally of finite presentation over $\mathbb{Z}$.

If $f\colon X\to S$ is a morphism of schemes, the universal property of pullbacks induces a map $f'\colon X\to X_\text{dR}\times_{S_\text{dR}} S$. Now checking what you want becomes simpler: $f$ is formally unramified (resp. formally smooth) if and only if $f'$ is monic (resp. epic).